# C++ runtime error pythonw

Tags: c++, python, windows, matplotlib, pythonw

I have been trying to run a script to generate a `mandelbrot image` using matplotlib however I am getting a very peculiar error. I am running the script through IDLE, running it for the first time does nothing but running it again after that brings up a window that says:

```
"Runtime error!

Program: C:\Python27\pythonw.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way."
```

The name of the window that pops up is `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library`

I have previously gotten errors about pythonw when trying to run image related stuff, usually the plot will stop responding and a message displays "pythonw.exe has stopped working".

I have searched high and low for a solution to this and google shows a few people having similar problems but no one replying to their posts.

I have also tried installing microsoft visual x64 C++ 2010 redistributed package but that aborted stating that there was a more up to date version present
interestingly looking through windows update history shows some failed security updates for microsoft visual C++ 2008 that did later install. (don't know if thats relavent)

Running windows 7 64 bit and python 2.7

Was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to what was going on and how to fix it because I sure don't

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like there is something similar here : http://bugs.python.org/issue9890

Comment: Yeh, but the original problem (similar to mine) doesn't seem to get answered and the thread is hijacked halfway down. I did try the solution to the second problem and removed the other python references from the path didn't seem to help. I also had a look at the pathbrowser in IDLE and that all seems to be pointing to the right place